# "you are pushing me away" vs. "you push me away"

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-continuous

Again I am wondering which version is more suitable:

> "Do you love me?"
>
> "I don`t know."

Should the response be:

> "You do know that whenever you say that you don't know whether you love me or not, **you are pushing me away**.

or:

> You do know that whenever you say that you don't know whether you love me or not, **you push me away**.

(I would probably use "you are pushing me").

Comment: Every one of your questions so far has been edited by community members. It's time to start learning from those edits. Dialogues and quotes should be but in a "quote box" (accomplished by using a ">" character at the front of a line). Make sure you insert line breaks where needed (two blank spaces at the end of a line will help). Avoid mashing two versions together with a slash – write them out separately so they are easier to read and analyze. And do not use long quotes for the title of your question. (More title advice found [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630).)

Answer (score 2):

Either is possible. The continuous "you are pushing me away" focuses on each indvidual occasion (because the so-called continuous is the form normally used for here-and-now for most verbs). "You push me away" is habitual, and so adequately expresses what the speaker wants to say, but without the focus on the individual actions.